# Custom filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some problem with custom filter. I can't include it's in my project. Firstly I used a filter: text. I understand that array initialized asynchronously and used this custom filter. But when i include this filter, i have problem ($injector:unpr). Sorry for my English.

```
<div ng-controller="ProductList as products">
      <form ng-submit="addProduct()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter product" ng-model="productTitle">
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="productList">
        <li ng-repeat="product in list track by $index | custom:search">
          {{product.title}}      
        </li>
      </ul>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
</div>
```

App is here

```
angular.module('lists', [])
  .controller('ProductList', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.addProduct = function() {
        $scope.list.push({title:$scope.productTitle});
        $scope.productTitle = "";
    }
  });
```

And filter is

```
.filter('custom', function() {
  return function(input, search) {
    if (!input) return input;
    if (!search) return input;
    var expected = ('' + search).toLowerCase();
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) {
      var actual = ('' + value).toLowerCase();
      if (actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1) {
        result[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker? try use not minified angular version and post full message for `i have problem ($injector:unpr)`

Comment: See this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). Notice that the filter is defined with a new module which is later passed to the main module. You are missing that part.

Comment: @EricMartinez, we don't know where is defined filter, possibly it defined in same module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code and issue seems to be the place the filter is being applied.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfgkna8k/2/. Though I didn't know what you were exactly implementing.

please check the code

```
<div ng-app="lists">
    <div ng-controller="ProductList as products">
          <form ng-submit="addProduct()">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter product" ng-model="productTitle" />
            <button>Add</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="productList">
            <li ng-repeat="product in list track by $index" ng-bind="filteredtitle = (product.title  | custom: searchBox)" ng-show="filteredtitle">

            </li>
          </ul>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchBox" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually, i need this: when I inpyt some value in "searchBox" in <ul class="productList"> displayed only those products. your code is dont worc correctly.

Comment: This is the code implemented by you. I just made the filter part work as that was the thing mentioned in the question.